# Is it this function uniformly continuous?

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity

Is $f(x) = \cos (e^x)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,+\infty)$?

I saw that in $0$ exist and it's limitate the limit of the fuction, so for Haine-Cantor the fuction is uniformly continuous on $[0,M]$. I don't know how to do when $x$ goes to infinite. How can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_{k}=\ln k\pi$ for $k=1,2,\dots$ then $\left|f\left(x_{2k}\right)-f\left(x_{2k+1}\right)\right|=2$
while $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left|x_{2k}-x_{2k+1}\right|=0$.

This contradicts that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\left(0,\infty\right)$.

E.g. no $\epsilon>0$ can be found with $|x-y|<\epsilon\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Prove that, despite $f(x)$ being a twice differentiable and bounded function, $f'(x)$ is unbounded. Using Lagrange's theorem, prove that the uniform continuity of $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: can you please state the " Lagrange Theorem "? Thank You.

Comment: @SrinivasK: if $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=f'(\xi)$ for some $\xi\in(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and ‎$‎‎\lim_{x\to a ‎^{+}‎} ‎f(x)‎$‎ and $‎‎‎‎‎\lim_{x\to b ‎^{-}‎} ‎f(x)‎$ exist, ‎then ‎‎$‎f(x)‎$ ‎is ‎uniformly ‎continuous‎

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful theorem for these type of questions which says that : If the limit of a function exists at +/- infinity and the function is continuous , then the function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: This is useless here, because it is only an "if" statement, and the hypothesis doesn't apply in this context.

Comment: @Ian Actually , i think it is an "iff" statement.i.e., if the limit at infinity doesn't exist, it cannot be uniformly continuous.

Comment: Absolutely not; consider $\sin(x)$.

Comment: @Ian sorry. my mistake. Is there any condition we can prove about the behaviour of uniformly continuous functions at +/- infinity ?

Comment: You need some additional hypothesis. For example, if $f$ is absolutely integrable and uniformly continuous, then it has limit zero at infinity. This is not true if $f$ is absolutely integrable and just continuous. An example of the latter case is given by a function which consists of countably many triangles, each of height $2$ and width $1/n^2$, located on each interval $[n,n+1]$. Then the integral is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ which is convergent, but the limit at infinity doesn't exist.