# Prove $\sin(e^x)$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, continuity

A task is given to prove that $f(x)=\sin(e^x)$ is not uniformly continuous in $\mathbb R$.

They're giving a hint, to first calculate $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \Big (\ln(2 \pi n + \frac \pi 2)-\ln(2\pi n) \Big )$. I didn't really understand why it is necessary, and didn't try to use the hint.

I tried a different approach: I know that if a function $f$ is differentiable in an interval $I$, and its derivative $f'$ is bounded in that interval, then $f$ is uniformly continuous. The contrapositive of this statement is that if $f$ is NOT uniformly distributed then it is either not differentiable OR $f'$ is not bounded.

$f'$ is $e^x\cos(e^x)$, which is not bounded, so this would mean that $f$ is not uniformly continuous. Am I wrong anywhere with my logic? If yes, then how do I prove this statement with the hint?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1133725.

Comment: Having bounded derivative is (for differentiable functions) equivalent to being Lipschitz continuous. This is **much** stronger than uniform continuity. You only show that the function is not Lipschitz. So: Your logic is flawed.

Comment: Hint: $f:(X,d)\to (Y, d') $ is uniformly continuous iff $f$ preserve parallel sequences. ( $(x_n), (y_n) $ are parallel sequence if $d(x_n, y_n) \to 0$ ). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4491236/977780)

Comment: You correctly state a valid theorem and then state its valid contrapositive, before trying to use its [invalid] inverse.  In symbols, if we know $\lnot B \to \lnot A$ and $\lnot A$ we cannot validly conclude $\lnot B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $x_n=\ln(2\pi n+\pi/2)$ and $y_n=\ln(2\pi n)$. Then, $$\sin(e^{x_n})=1\quad \text{and}\quad \sin(e^{y_n})=0.$$
Since, $$|x_n-y_n|\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow } 0,$$ the function $x\mapsto \sin(e^x)$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: But is my proof wrong? It seems simpler, so I wonder why it wasn't done this way.

Comment: You simply mixed things. It's indeed true that if $f$ is not uniformly continuous, then $f$ is not differentiable or $f$ is differentiable but $f'$ is not bounded, but I don't understand why if $f'$ is not bounded, then $f$ wouldn't be uniformly continuous (at least, $f(x)=\sin(e^x)$ is a counter example). @MCFromScratch

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your answer with the sequences? Why these sequences and conditions imply that $f$ is not uniformly continuous?

Comment: Because, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there are $x_n,y_n$ s.t. $|x_n-y_n|<\frac{1}{n}$ but $|\sin(e^{x_n})-\sin(e^{y_n})|\geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Is it always enough to show that if $f(x)-f(y) = c$ for some function $f$ and constant $c$, then $f$ is not uniformly continuous? Because it can never be smaller than $\epsilon < c$?

Comment: your question is unclear. It's enough to have sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ s.t. $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$ when $n\to \infty $ and $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=c$ for some $c>0$.